# Appium Driver Instance :- java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, appium, apache-commons-httpclient

I have following capabilities for Appium

This are the jar in my class path

- gson-2.2.4.jar
- hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
- hamcrest-library-1.3.jar
- httpclient-4.2.1.jar
- httpcore-4.2.1.jar
- java-client-2.1.0.jar
- json-20080701.jar
- selenium-java-2.42.2.jar
- selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar

  DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
          capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
          capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "5.0.2");
          capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Android Emulator");
          capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Chrome");
          driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:5723/wd/hub"),
                  capabilities);

And Stack-trace is

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.HttpClientConnectionOperator.<init>(HttpClientConnectionOperator.java:75)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:149)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:136)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:112)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.getClientConnectionManager(HttpClientFactory.java:68)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.<init>(HttpClientFactory.java:55)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.<init>(HttpCommandExecutor.java:99)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.<init>(HttpCommandExecutor.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:153)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:109)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:39)
    at test.mypoint.mobile.MyPointTest1.setUp(MyPointTest1.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Comment: Where is code to get APK file  from path??

Comment: As chrome is default app, it doesn't required. There are two ways appium support 1. Full reset or without reset